# How to run a tflite model on desktop GPU like CUDA?

Tags: tensorflow, gpgpu

I am try to run mobilenet_v2_1.0_224.tflite model on my desktop ubuntu and Cuda GPU.
But its running only on CPU by default.

How can I make it to run on cuda GPU as well?

BTW, am able to run the same on mobile device accelerators using nnapi.
Regards,